# A pm.sendRequest from a function body in Postman doesn't work

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, postman-pre-request-script

I'm trying to call a request from a function body. But it looks like pm.sendRequest(request, function(err, response)... is ignoring. Where I'm wrong?

```
utils = {
    myFunc: function(email, password) {
        var user_status = "none";
        var endpoint = pm.environment.get("url")+"/login";
        request = {
            url: endpoint,
            method: "POST",
            body: {
                mode: 'raw',
                raw: JSON.stringify({'email': email,
                                    'password': password
                                    })
            },
            header: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        };
        // console.info(request);
 
        // doesn't execute or ignore pm.sendRequest call
        pm.sendRequest(request, function(err, response) {
            console.info("requestName", pm.info.requestName);
            user_status = "exists";
            pm.environment.set("user_status", user_status);
            console.warn("Warning: The user already exists.");
            pm.environment.set("user_status", user_status);
        });
        return user_status;
    }
};
```

`console.log(utils.myFunc(email, password));`

I have got no console output from the inner pm.sendRequest code block.
The same thing with
Object.prototype.is_user_registered = function(email, password) {...